# onTouchEvent called with ACTION_UP while finger still touches the screen

Tags: android

I have a game when the user has to drag some object. The problem is that objects are frequently dropped when dragged on Android (the game is multiplatform and works fine on iOS).

I logged calls to onTouchEvent and when objects are dropped onTouchEvent is called twice in quick succession (~20ms). The first call is ACTION_UP and then ACTION_DOWN. I don’t think my finger really stopped touching the screen when these events were raised so it looks like these events are superfluous.

I am able to repro this on Nexus 7 2013.

Any ideas what can cause these superfluous touch events?

Comment: have you tested on other devices? sometimes this happens when the touchscreen is malfunctioning, or when it's a bit wet.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only this Nexus so I can’t test on other devices.

Comment: I had the same problem, it was device's fault.